# What to choose to implement deque?

Tags: java

What would you rather choose to implement deque: HashSet or LinkedList. And could you state cons and pros for both please?
Thank you.

Comment: This is a typical homework/interview question. If true, in the future please tag those questions as such.

Comment: ArrayDeque with the pros that it is done!

Comment: Yes that is homework question. Didn't know that I can mark it as such.

Comment: You should do, because some questions like this one are actually a poser (while you didn't know that beforehand) and *may* get closed as "no real question". Also, the answerers can then suit the answers better to the question (e.g. more "simple" explanation and/or no complete code examples). BTW: you should already have found out the answer when you just peek a bit in the API docs: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course LinkedList. All Dequeue operations there are implemented strictly as O(1) and no excessive memory is used.

Answer (score 3):

A `HashSet` is not a `Deque` so you would have to use a `LinkedList` (which does implement `Deque`).  The reason behind this is that `HashSet` is not an ordered data structure, and hence cannot be used as a queue.

For thread-safe blocking implementations of `Deque` consider [`LinkedBlockingDeque`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) or [`ArrayDeque`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html).

Answer (score 1):

HashSet is not an alternative, because a set does not record the order in which the element was added. Additionally, a set does not allow the same element to be added more than once.

LinkedList is a better option or why not using an existing [Deque](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) implementation?